# How to submit from a razor view a list in a model with dynamic list? ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

First of all, I have these models

```cs
public class Event
{
    //other properties
    public IEnumerable<EventsParticipants> ParticipantsList { get; set; }
}

public class EventsParticipants
{
    public string ParticipantId { get; set; }
    public int EventId{ get; set; }
}
```

`ParticipantId` stores an Identity User Id so that I can relate those two tables.

I've made this dynamic list so that I can add users to events in an "UpdateEvent" Razor view.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a onclick="addToList(this)">(click me)User to add into list(click me)</a>
<br/>
<select multiple id="participantsList"
style="height: 7em; overflow-y: scroll; width: 10em"></select>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="removeFromList()">Remove</button>
<button type="button" onclick="clearList()">Clear list</button>

    <script>
    function addToList(usuario) {
        var lista = document.getElementById("participantsList");
        var item = document.createElement("option");
        item.text = $(usuario).text()
        lista.appendChild(item);
    }
    
    function removeFromList() {
        $("#participantsList option:selected").remove();
    }

    function clearList() {
        $("#participantsList").empty();
    }
    </script>
```

This list together with other properties about `Event` should be posted to database.

But I'm struggling really hard to find a way to fetch that data after User finishes adding items to it.

---

**UPDATE:**

Ok, after a long time away from the project, I dove into it again.
I'm thankful for the help, though. Without it I wouldn't be able to get to this solution.

I didn't change the collection type of EventsParticipants, but I did modify my model to provide better functionality.

Here's how it looks now:

```
public class Participant
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
}
```

Now, about my view. I decided to dump tag helpers and went with HTML name attribute - this way I get to submit a form with array syntax. Since it doesn't work with `<option>` tags, I made some JavaScript to create hidden `<input>` tags just before submission.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a onclick="addToList(this)">User (click to add)</a>
<br/>
<select multiple id="participants-list"
style="height: 7em; overflow-y: scroll; width: 10em"></select>
<div hidden id="submission"></div>
<br/>
<input type="submit" onclick="submitList()" value="Submit"/>
<button type="button" onclick="removeFromList()">Remove</button>
<button type="button" onclick="clearList()">Clear list</button>

    <script>
    function submitList() {
        let selectedList = $('#participants-list').children();
        for (i = 0; i < selectedList.length; i++) {
            let submissionInput = document.createElement('input');
            submissionInput.setAttribute('name', 'ParticipantsList[' + i + '].username');
            submissionInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
            submissionInput.value = $(selectedList[i]).val();
            $('#submission').append(submissionInput);
        }
    }
    
    function addToList(user) {
        var list = document.getElementById("participants-list");
        var item = document.createElement("option");
        item.text = $(user).text();
        item.value = $(user).attr('id');
        list.append(item);
    }
    
    function removeFromList() {
        $("#participants-list option:selected").remove();
    }

    function clearList() {
        $("#participants-list").empty();
    }
    </script>
```

Within the controller, I validate Username and fill the Name property.

I don't know if that's a good way to design this, but I did like the result. I appreciate, however, any feedback you may share :).

Comment: Do you want to post the dropdown-list to an action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fetch the data, there are a few things to note:

1.Set a name (participantsList) to the select list:

`<select multiple id="participantsList" name="participantsList" style="height: 7em; overflow-y: scroll; width: 10em"></select>`

2.When submit the form, only the value of the selected option will be submit, so you need set `value` and `selected` attribute to option.

```
function addToList(usuario) {
    var lista = document.getElementById("participantsList");
    var item = document.createElement("option");
    item.text = $(usuario).text();
    item.value = $(usuario).text();
    item.selected = true;
    lista.appendChild(item);
}
```

3.As @Mohamed Adel said, use a `list<string>` to accept the list.

Below is a test:

**Model:**

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> ParticipantsList { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model Event

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<form asp-action="UpdateEvent" method="post">
    <div>
        <input asp-for="Id" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="Name" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <a onclick="addToList(this)">(click me)User to add into list(click me)</a>
        <br />
        <select multiple id="participantsList" name="participantsList"
                style="height: 7em; overflow-y: scroll; width: 10em"></select>
        <br />
        <button type="button" onclick="removeFromList()">Remove</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="clearList()">Clear list</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="sumit" />
    </div>
</form>

@section scripts{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function addToList(usuario) {
            var lista = document.getElementById("participantsList");
            var item = document.createElement("option");
            item.text = $(usuario).text();
            item.value = $(usuario).text();
            item.selected = true;
            lista.appendChild(item);
        }

        function removeFromList() {
            $("#participantsList option:selected").remove();
        }

        function clearList() {
            $("#participantsList").empty();
        }
    </script>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult UpdateEvent(Event myevent)
{
    return View();
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
 public class EventsDto
 {
   //other properties
   public List<string> ParticipantsIds { get; set; }
 }
```

Then in view so after submit you can get list of ParticipantsIds you can loop on them then initiate new objects of EventsParticipants finally add them to DB

```
@model EventsDto
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<a onclick="addToList(this)">(click me)User to add into list(click me)</a>
<br/>
<select asp-for="ParticipantsIds" multiple id="participantsList"
style="height: 7em; overflow-y: scroll; width: 10em"></select>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="removeFromList()">Remove</button>
<button type="button" onclick="clearList()">Clear list</button>


<script>
function addToList(usuario) {
    var lista = document.getElementById("participantsList");
    var item = document.createElement("option");
    item.text = $(usuario).text()
    lista.appendChild(item);
}

function removeFromList() {
    $("#participantsList option:selected").remove();
}

function clearList() {
    $("#participantsList").empty();
}
</script>
```